# Support of a pushforward measure

Tags: measure-theory

Can we see something about $\text{supp}(h_{\#} \mu)$ if we know $\text{supp}(\mu)$ with $\mu$ a probability on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $h$ a mesurable function.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You need continuity of $h$ to say something about the support of the pushforward measure.

Comment: Okay what can we say in that case ? For my problem it's enough so your comment is actually an answer :).